# Kafka Stream: Transform method stateless

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Can I use the transform without a state, even if that means changing the key to something else?

Note: I am limited to the methods corresponding to the following version (page):

https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `transform()` without state. Note, that the last parameter `stateStoreNames` is for options var-args type `String...` that allows to pass in zero, one, or more store names.

Not sure what you mean by "even if that means changing the key to something else"

Comment: Thanks.  Just trying to visualize how and where transformed results will be kept without state store if we do the rekey, would it be just in memory after the transformation?

Comment: If you don't write the result stream to a topic via `to()` (as an example) the result records would be dropped. That is the same behavior as for any other operator, like map() or filter().